# how can I configure Gunicorn to handle a flask app having multiple threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, gunicorn

My flask app uses threading packages to handle scheduled jobs(cron type).
It works fine when I use `python hello.py` but it doesn't work with Gunicorn `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app`

Can Gunicorn handle multithreaded app?
how can I configure it to handle my app?

here is my hello.py https://gist.github.com/prrraveen/fafb4e1de14d39c1e0e5454f3d322114

Answer (score 2):

The function `run_continuously()` would never be called under gunicorn as it loads your code as a module and not as a main program as would occur if run as a script, thus `__name__` will never be `__main__`.